# Prove that the group $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ is generated by at least $n$ elements

Tags: group-theory

I need to prove that the group $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ with the regular $+$ operation is generated by at least $n$ elements. I know it's pretty analog to the case of vector spaces..
I tried induction (because the base case here is easy) via quotient group, but it didn't work.

Thanks !

Comment: do you mean $\mathbb Z^n=\underbrace{\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z\ldots \times\mathbb Z}$?

Comment: Yes, and $ \left(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}\right)+\left(b_{1},\ldots,b_{n}\right)=\left(a_{1}+b_{1},\ldots,a_{n}+b_{n}\right)
 $

Comment: It is trivial to prove that it is generated by at least $n$ elements. What you mean is that you want to prove that it cannot be generated by fewer than $n$ elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\mathbb Z^n$ is generated by $v_1,\ldots, v_m$. Then these $m$ vectors, viewed as elements of $\mathbb Q^n$,  also span $\mathbb Q^n$ as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space (for $v\in\mathbb Q^n$, there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ with $Nv\in \mathbb Z^n$; then $Nv=\sum a_iv_i$ implies $v=\sum\frac{a_i}{N}v_i$). Since $\dim\mathbb Q^n=n$, this implies $m\ge n$.

Comment: Need to refresh my linear algebra skills, thanks !

Comment: BTW, note that $S_3\times S_3$ is generated by two elements, not four as one might naively expect.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose every element $z\in\mathbb Z$ can be written as 
$$z=\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i z_i, k<n$$

Every element of $\mathbb Q^n$ also can be writen as
$$ \frac p q=\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha _i \frac {p_i}{q_i}$$
 where $p_i,q_i\in\mathbb Z$
So, the dimension of the vector space $\mathbb Q^n\leq k<n$ over $\mathbb Q$.
which is a contradiction to $dim\, \mathbb Q^n=n$ .